# Skip list node add() fails

Tags: java, skip-lists

I have this code for a skip list I modified from a source online, the add(x) method somewhat works.

```
add(5);
add(4);
add(7);
```

it works when you add a number like 5, then any number smaller than the last number, like 4 but once it get to 7 or any number larger than the previous it gets stuck in a loop, and I cannot see why.

```
package assignment1;

public class Node {
    public static int item;
    public static Node[] next;
    public static int MAX_LEVEL = 6;
    public static int level;
    public static int n;
    public static Node head = new Node(MAX_LEVEL, 0);


    public Node(int level, int value){
        next = new Node[level + 1];
        this.item = value;
    }
    public static int randomLevel() {
        int lvl = (int)(Math.log(1. * -Math.random()) / Math.log(1. * -0.5));
        return Math.min(lvl, MAX_LEVEL);
    } 

    public static void add(int value){
        Node current = head;    
        Node[] update = new Node[MAX_LEVEL + 1];

        for (int i = level; i >= 0; i--) {
        while (current.next[i] != null && current.next[i].item - value < 0) {
            current = current.next[i];
        }
        update[i] = current; 
    }
    current = current.next[0];

        if (current == null || current.item != value) {        
        int lvl = randomLevel();

            if (lvl > level) {
                for (int i = level + 1; i <= lvl; i++) {
                update[i] = head;
        }
                level = lvl;
        }
            current = new Node(lvl, value);
        for (int i = 0; i <= lvl; i++) {
            current.next[i] = update[i].next[i];
            update[i].next[i] = current;
        }
            n++;
        }
    }

    public static void remove(int value){
        Node current = head;    
        Node[] update = new Node[MAX_LEVEL + 1];

        for (int i = level; i >= 0; i--) {
        while (current.next[i] != null && current.next[i].item - value < 0) {
            current = current.next[i];
            }
        update[i] = current; 
    }
    current = current.next[0];

        if (current.item == value) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= level; i++) {
            if (update[i].next[i] != current){
                break;
            }
            update[i].next[i] = current.next[i];
        }
            while (level > 0 && head.next[level] == null) {
            level--;
        }
            n--;
        }
    }

    public static void list(){
        Node current = head;
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            System.out.print(current.item + ",");
            current = current.next[0];
        }
        System.out.print("]");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        add(10);
        add(9);
        add(8);
        add(7);
        add(6);
        add(5);
        add(4);
        add(3);
        add(2);
        add(1);
        list();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I uploaded the entire code I developed, the code is from a Textbook of mine that is in Pseudocode, it needed to be adapted into Java format. I cannot see why its failing.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with `MAX_LEVEL=6`? (hint)

Comment: I do not see it, I tried lowering/increasing `MAX_LEVEL` removing it and replacing all the calls to it with `randomLevel();`

Comment: You're right. I apologize, I did not do a good analysis and jumped to a premature conclusion. I posted an answer but I think it was totally wrong. Where did you get the skip list code online? Did you modify the add method?

Comment: I don't think you're iterating through `current` correctly in the while loop and when `current.next[i].item-value<0` is true, you're getting stuck, as you said in the code comment.

Comment: I cannot remember where I got the code, and since I recently reinstalled my OS, I lost the history. What I do remember is that the most I changed is the names of things to a format I am used too, to better understand the code.

Comment: Okay, well I want to try and help you since I previously led you astray. I found [this](http://www.mathcs.duq.edu/drozdek/DSinJava/SkipList.java) code. Take a look at it's "insert" method where it uses "prev" and "curr". I think you want to do something similar.

Comment: I am afraid the link to the code you provided has not helped me. I did upload the entire .java I made maybe there is more to what I missing. I have been stumped on this for a few days now.

Comment: When I run your code above I get all 1's in the list. Is it supposed to list 1 through 10 starting with 1?

Comment: Yes is should list 1-10 with the list function I changed the numbers to check if the problem persists. Now I am completely stumped on this.

Comment: There are many implementations of a skip list in Java on the web if you just Google "java skip list example" surely one of them is a working implementation. Is this a homework assignment or are you just trying to learn something new in Java, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Ultimately it is part of a homework assignment, the assignment(question) is to create a method to swap two elements in the list, I can use code online, or that I create my self for the rest. I find it best to find code and adapt it for myself to better understand what is happening.

Comment: Are you required to use a skip list implementation? Just swapping two elements in an array (or adding a number to an array and sorting it) isn't very hard and is quite different from a skip list.

Comment: There are parts to the swap, swap 2 elements in a singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list, and skip-list. It is specific to that data type. I've already done the other 2 those were easy, the skip list is the one that's got me.

Comment: Oh okay. Is the code above something they give you to start with or are starting from scratch?

Comment: The code above I developed myself from the code provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73380/discussion-between-binaryjudy-and-drew-s).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what was wrong with your implementation so here is a working one, that you can study and should get you on the right path:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SkipList
{
private class Node
{
    private int item;
    private Node[] next;

    public Node(int value, int level)
    {
        this.item = value;
        next = new SkipList.Node[level+1];
    }

    public int level()
    {
        return next.length-1;
    }
}

private  Node head;
private int size;

/**
 * Constructs a new, empty instance of SkipList.
 */
public SkipList()
{
    head = new Node(0, 0);
    size = 0;
}

private int randomLevel()
{
    int level;

    Random rand = new Random();

    for (level = 0; rand.nextInt() % 2 == 0; level++)
        ;

    return level;
}


public void add(int item)
{
    int maxLevel = head.level();

    Node current = head;

    Node[] nodePath = new SkipList.Node[maxLevel + 1];

    for (int level = maxLevel; level >= 0; level--)
    {
        while (current.next[level] != null && item > current.next[level].item)
        {
            current = current.next[level];
        }

        nodePath[level] = current;
    }

    current = current.next[0];

    if (current != null && item==(current.item))
    {
        return;
    } 
    else
    {
        int nodeLevel = randomLevel();

        if (nodeLevel > maxLevel)
        {
            head.next = Arrays.copyOf(head.next, nodeLevel + 1);

            nodePath = Arrays.copyOf(nodePath, nodeLevel + 1);

            for (int level = maxLevel + 1; level <= nodeLevel; level++)
            {
                nodePath[level] = head;
            }

            maxLevel = nodeLevel;
        }

        current = new Node(item, nodeLevel);

        for (int level = 0; level <= nodeLevel; level++) {
            current.next[level] = nodePath[level].next[level];

            nodePath[level].next[level] = current;
        }

        size++;
    }
}



public void list()
{
    Node current = head.next[0];
    System.out.print("[");
    while(current != null)
    {
        System.out.print(current.item + ",");
        current = current.next[0];
    }
    System.out.println("\b]");
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SkipList theList= new SkipList();

    theList.add(10);
    theList.add(9);
    theList.add(8);
    theList.add(11);
    theList.add(6);
    theList.add(5);
    theList.add(7);
    theList.add(3);
    theList.add(4);
    theList.add(1);
    theList.add(2);
    theList.list();
}
}
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```